# Is it possible to disable caching on a specific address range

Tags: caching, memory, arm, embedded

I configured my ethernet module to store the received data in a specific address range in RAM, say `xxxx-yyyy`. When the cache is enabled I cannot receive the data, since the data are read from the cache instead of the actual Ethernet buffers. The problem was resolved by disabling the cache as explained [here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0458c/Chdhgibd.html), but I am wondering if there is a way to disable caching only in this specific address Range  `xxxx-yyyy`

Target processor arm cortex r7

**Update**

I configured the MPU, the attributes of the region containing the buffers are
:Access permission = FULL, Type= Shareable device

`mov r0, #10
 mcr p15, 0, r0, c6, c2, 0
 ldr r0, =(0xxxx)               //REGION_BASE
 mcr p15, 0, r0, c6, c1, 0       // DRBAR
 mcr p15, 0, r0, c6, c1, 1       // IRBAR
 ldr r0, =(0x18 | 0x1)           // REGION_SIZE
 mcr p15, 0, r0, c6, c1, 2       // DRSR
 mcr p15, 0, r0, c6, c1, 3       // IRSR
 ldr r0, =(0x1301)               // Shareable Device
 mcr p15, 0, r0, c6, c1, 4       // DRACR
 mcr p15, 0, r0, c6, c1, 5       // IRACR`

After configuring the MPU I activated the caching as follows:

`MRC p15, 0, R1, c1, c0, 0  ; Read System Control Register configuration data
ORR R1, R1, #0x1 <<12      ; instruction cache enable
MCR p15, 0, r0, c7, c5, 0  ; Invalidate entire instruction cache
MCR p15, 0, R1, c1, c0, 0  ; enabled instruction cache
ISB`

And then the Ethernet data are not anymore received, I have the feeling that the MPU configuration is overwritten after enabling the caching

Comment: that is one of the jobs of an MMU, you enable and disable memory regions from access, cachable or not, etc.  How did you enable data caching in the first place?

Comment: ahh, as answered below looks like it doesnt have an mmu necessarily but an mpu but that would have been something you configured to get the cache on in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, actually I configured the MPU and then I activate caching, I have the feeling that the MPU configuration are not taken into consideration, see the Update

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

Look at your MPU users guide to set up regions as cachable, non-cachable, plus the write back policies.

You can also invalidate (discard) or clean (commit) regions from the cache, which might be easier and more useful than simply going non-cachable.  The MPU only has 16 or so regions you can specify.

Comment: Scultz, Thanks for the answer, actually I configured the MPU and then I activate caching, I have the feeling that the MPU configuration are not taken into consideration, see the Update